# List of blogs to learn more about Ubuntu

Tags: community

Add blogs and websites that are useful in the quest to know/learn more about Ubuntu.

*One blog per answer, please - you can vote answers up/down as you feel appropriate. If you feel the blog is biased towards or is good for particular tasks, please mention them.*

Comment: I've added some answers myself. Please add some more blogs to the list if you know any..

Comment: Per the [subjective guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), I've downvoted every answer that merely lists a blog name.

Comment: This has received a bit of attention and should not be closed. Who voted to do so?

Comment: I recommend posting a question on meta, before close-voting this question; as ObsessiveFOSS suggests, there seems to be quite a bit of community support for it to be open.

Answer (score 70):

[OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/)

Comment: Big focus on desktop apps and bling. One that I watch though.

Comment: Lots of updates about the upcoming versions/developments of Ubuntu here. Its a good way of checking what's up without running the latest alphas.

Comment: Nothing more than a tabloid

Comment: disagree, I think there's good content on there. I've found a dozen useful things I wouldn't have know about otherwise, including ubuntu stackexchange

Comment: It's less about learning technical stuff (like programming or system administration) and more about discovery and having fun with Ubuntu (like themes, design ideas, and new apps). OMG! Ubuntu! is not without its own share of controversy; people seem to either like it or hate it.

Answer (score 44):

[Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/)

"A blog on Linux (mostly Ubuntu) and open source / web applications and news". It is regularly updated, and the posts are always useful and well-written.

Comment: A perfect blog for users of Ubuntu

Answer (score 42):

[Planet Ubuntu](http://planet.ubuntu.com/) is a blog aggregator. Not every post will be about Ubuntu but there's a good selection of blogs within it.

Comment: Several of the blogs listed in this community wiki are aggregated by Planet Ubuntu, including the Canonical Design Blog, Mark Shuttleworth's blog, Full Circle Magazine (Ronnie Tucker), Ubuntu Linux Tips & Tricks (Mackenzie Morgan), The Fridge, and Jono Bacon. It's a good source for finding blogs to subscribe to even if you don't want to subscribe to Planet Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 23):

[Canonical Design Blog](http://design.canonical.com)

A great place to learn about upcoming design changes and why they are being made, provide feedback, or even get involved in the design of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11):

[How To Geek Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/tag/ubuntu/)

Comment: Random spaghetti compilation.

Answer (score 10):

[Mark Shuttleworth Blog](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/)

Founder of the Ubuntu Project.

Comment: Mark's blog certainly talks about Ubuntu, but it isn't much of a learning tool.

Comment: I agree with Erigami. He doesn't update it very often and he doesn't help much with learning about Ubuntu. However, it is useful for getting the occasional update on what direction Ubuntu is headed in.

Answer (score 10):

[Ubuntu UK Podcast](http://podcast.ubuntu-uk.org/)

Ubuntu podcast from the UK.

Answer (score 8):

[Full Circle Magazine](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/)

Not a blog as such, but is a free monthly (PDF) magazine with a particular emphasis on how-to articles and reader submitted stories. It does feature some news stories too.

Answer (score 7):

[Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/)

Comment: This one's really great for getting answers. I could probably attribute them to 1/4 of the share of answers I've gotten from various sites over the past 2-4 months.

Answer (score 7):

[The Fridge](http://ubuntu-news.org/)

Ubuntu's official news source. It includes the Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter and other blog posts.

Answer (score 6):

[Ubuntu Linux Tips & Tricks](http://ubuntulinuxtipstricks.blogspot.com) **Discontinued**

Comment: This blog is not active any more.

Answer (score 5):

[2buntu.com](http://2buntu.com/)

It's a newer site that's growing fast. They talk about Ubuntu, and to a certain extent Linux in general.

Disclaimer: This is one of the many, many blogs that I contribute to from time to time.

Comment: And we write a number of tutorials as well. (I'm a contributor too.)

Answer (score 4):

[Jonobacon](http://www.jonobacon.org/)

Comment: Jono talks mostly about community,so no.

Comment: You can learn an awful lot from Jonos blog. Not just about the community, and I don't see how learning about the Ubuntu community is a bad thing anyway!

Answer (score 4):

[apt-get install debian-wizard](http://raphaelhertzog.com)

Disclaimer: This is my blog, I'm a Debian developer and Ubuntu member and write articles for Debian/Ubuntu users and contributors.

Answer (score 3):

[Works with U](http://www.workswithu.com/) points to [The Var Guy](http://www.thevarguy.com/category/ubuntu/)

Answer (score 3):

[Debuntu](http://www.debuntu.org/)

Site provides how-tos, tutorials, tips and tricks for Debian-based distribution such as Ubuntu and Knoppix.

Answer (score 3):

[Ubuntu Vibes](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/)

Answer (score 3):

[Ubuntu Weblogs](http://ubuntuweblogs.org/) is another aggregator for Ubuntu-related blogs. It stays pretty much on-topic at the cost of fewer updates. According to their "About" section:

> Unlike Planet Ubuntu, this Planet is
>   open to anyone who writes about Ubuntu
>   or any derivative.

Comment: [Ubuntu Universe](http://ubuntuweblogs.org/universe/) is almost the same thing (even found at the same domain), except it also includes posts by these bloggers that aren't about Ubuntu or its derivatives. I don't think there's any Ubuntu-related material there not already posted on the main [Ubuntu Weblogs](http://ubuntuweblogs.org/) site.

Comment: Ubuntu Weblogs went offline in May or June of 2013 (and currently it's just a parked domain with worthless advertising links unrelated to Ubuntu). However, the old Ubuntu Weblogs content can still be accessed [via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510071108/http://ubuntuweblogs.org).

Answer (score 3):

[Tuxradar](http://tuxradar.com/)

Answer (score 3):

[Tech Drive-in](http://techdrivein.com) 'Technology, Linux, Ubuntu FTW'

Answer (score 3):

[www.ubuntubuzz.com](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com)

*Discover what's new in ubuntu*
 - It's provide news, article, how to, and update PPA,  you can also participate by writing article/news there, come in .

Answer (score 2):

[Linoob](http://www.linoob.com/)

It's a pretty decent blog on Ubuntu. It's not updated as often as the blogs listed above, however has many good articles for learning Ubuntu as well as few good tips and tricks.

Answer (score 2):

[Bodhizazen Blog](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/) ...................

Answer (score 1):

I have my own site (DorkBlog) but it's private at the moment.
Should you desire to view it, I'd need to allow your IP. 
Or anyone's for that matter. :)

Probably the best I have found is [*nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/)
and [Commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse)
Not necessarily Ubuntu-specific, but good none-the-less to sharpen one's teeth on.

Answer (score 1):

There's [The Linux Action Show](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=4) which isn't an Ubuntu specific video podcast exactly, but they do cover everything that's new in the Linux/Unix community in general (and there's something happening to Ubuntu quite often these days).

It's a weekly show which is being recorded live every Sunday. Every monday the show (+- 50 minutes) is delivered through rss and available on their website in every format you'd care about.

Topics range from [Linux gaming in general](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?p=3421), to [reviewing Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?p=2936) and derivatives like [Mint](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?p=2794).

**They do have their own opinion** and are (sometimes painfully) objective and stick to their own principles. If you can handle that, you're bound to appreciate their sense of humor.

Answer (score 1):

[Linux North](http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/)

Information on installation and use of Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS (long term support version).

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu Tutorials](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/) **Discontinued**

Answer (score 0):

[UpUbuntu Blog](http://www.upubuntu.com/) They cover so many topics but i liked installing kernel 3.3.4