# Where can I find the latest news on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10

Where can I find the latest news on Ubuntu 11.10? I'm interested in what default applications are going to be present in 11.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For getting news and stuff, you'll probably find all that information in this question: [List of blogs to learn more about Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594/list-of-blogs-to-learn-more-about-ubuntu)

You can find the notes for the default applications discussion here:

- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-default-apps
- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-default-email-client

Comment: Thanks! The launchpad discussions were exactly what I was looking for!